# how do i remove globasearch from my computer

Tags: virus-removal

I have noticed a few weeks/ month or so ago, that the 'new tab home page' on both of the web browsers I regularly used had started coming up with something called globa search. (i.e. when opening a new tab in the browser, the page that was automatically shown on the new tab was this globasearch thing)

At first, I thought this was just a change Mozilla had made to Firefox, but then I noticed it also happened in Chrome. I also noticed that this seemed to coincide with my computer becoming very slow and unresponsive.

After doing a bit of research, it seems this globasearch thing is a virus that I must have picked up from somewhere... I had run a few antivirus scans (using F- Secure Internet Security, and also downloaded and ran an Ad-Aware scan), but neither of these picked up any viruses, so I wasn't sure what was going on.

I've had a quick Google of how to remove globasearch from my computer, but every site I've looked at is telling me to download and run some 'spyware removal tool'. I'm not sure that I trust these sites... there's just something about the feel of them that makes me think that they're not genuine, so I'm reluctant to download the tools they've suggested.

I was just wondering if anyone on here knows how I can remove globasearch from my computer, since neither F-Secure nor Ad-Aware seem to be able to?

Cheers!

**Edit 11/12/2012 @ 19:50**

Ok, I ran a scan using Malwarebytes as suggested, and it removed a few threats (all of the ones it found), and told me to restart my computer. I did that, and when I then opened my browser, and opened a new tab, I was still given the globasearch page... Any other ideas as to how to remove this?

**Edit 12/12/2012 @ 00:45**

Ok, having run both Malwarebytes and Hitman separately, and also restarted my computer, when I open a browser, I'm still having the same trouble with it being ridiculously slow/ unresponsive (for example, while typing in this comment, I type a few words, and it takes about 5 seconds after I've stopped typing for those words to be displayed in the text box). Also, when I open a new tab, I still get this globasearch thing, so whatever malware has been removed, clearly neither of the tools have found this globasearch virus/ malware. Any other ideas as to how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Have you ran Malwarebyes yet?

Comment: No- is that an anti-spyware program or something?

Comment: Its a very well known security program.

Comment: Ok, great, I'll give it a go. Cheers

Comment: Ok, I ran a scan using Malwarebytes, and it removed a few threats (all of the ones it found), and told me to restart my computer. I did that, and when I then opened my browser, and opened a new tab, I was still given the globasearch page... Any other ideas as to how to remove this?

Comment: @omeone2088 - At least point asking on the Malwarebytes community forum would be best.  What your asking is far to specific to your problem.

Comment: I don't have a problem with Malwarebytes- I'd never heard of that until the first comment on my original question... What I have a problem with is this globasearch thing- someone suggested trying to use Malwarebytes to get rid of it- I tried and it didn't work. So I'm now asking if anyone knows another way of getting rid of globasearch- the same question as my original one.

Comment: They have trained personal with experience to help you locate and remove the infection.

Comment: Ah Ok, I'll give that a shot then. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you have mentioned Malwarebytes by that I assume you mean Malwarebytes Antimalware. However from what I gather this Globasearch is a rootkit infection.

While MBAM is an excellent program. Malwarebytes has recently introduced a dedicated free rootkit remover called Malware Antirootkit (Beta) - If it is anything as good as its sister program....watch out rootkits

http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/other_tools/

If that fails I would then try Hitman Pro (a 30 day free trial is available)

http://www.surfright.nl/en

If you look at the image at the bottom it removes Google redirection infection - ZoneAccess - which is exactly what Globasearch Rootkit is !

[image]

Comment: Ok, having run both Malwarebytes and Hitman separately, and also restarted my computer, when I open a browser, I'm still having the same trouble with it being ridiculously slow/ unresponsive (for example, while typing in this comment, I type a few words, and it takes about 5 seconds after I've stopped typing for those words to be displayed in the text box). Also, when I open a new tab, I still get this globasearch thing, so whatever malware has been removed, clearly neither of the tools have found this globasearch virus/ malware. Any other ideas as to how I can get rid of it?

Comment: The only other two I have experience of is Kaspersky's TDSSKiller so run that http://support.kaspersky.com/5350 and Bitdefender Bootkit Scan (scroll down and either choose 32 bit or 64 bit) http://techdows.com/2011/12/bootkit-removal-tool-from-bitdefender.html

Comment: If you are still having issues after that I would contact Hitman technical support: support@hitmanpro.com

Comment: See also this Superuser post entitled "How do I get rid of malicious spyware, malware, viruses or rootkits from my PC?" for additional excellent info http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/513005

Comment: @someone2088 - Here is a link to a v.good video about getting rid of Zero access rootkits (if you have not done so already)  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xVtGvtlDPwo